# Unique index is not working with heroku mongolab

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose, meanjs

I have deployed my mean.js application in heroku. I have updated my collection to add unique property to a field. It is throwing unique property error  when name duplicates in the local database. But in the heroku mongolab it is not giving error. I cannot figure it out. I tried with dropping the collection. Any idea about how to solve this?

```
var CateogrySchema = new Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    index: {unique: true, dropDups: true}
}, description: {
    type: String
},
deleted: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
}
});
```